# How to match two python lists and find missing values

Tags: python, list, match

I'm creating a function that syncs my db and an external email service, i wanted to get all users registered in this email service and match them with my db.

Is there a way in python for me to get two lists (one from my db and one from email service) and match if in db list have any email that it's not in email service's list so i can use it to register them?

Comment: Try `filter(lambda x: x not in list2, list1)`

Answer (score 1):

Cast the lists into sets and use a symmetric difference:

```
list(set(list1) ^ set(list2))
```

This will give you a list of differences between both lists. If you really only want what is missing from your email list, then subtract your database list from your email list:

```
list(set(email-list) - set(database-list))
```

This will give you a list of emails not already registered.